# Batch Job with Custom Iterable throwing error First error: Invalid conversion from runtime type CustomIterable to System.Iterable

Tags: apex, batch, iteration

I get the error First error: Invalid conversion from runtime type CustomIterable to System.Iterable when trying to use a customer iterable in a batch job.

My custom iterable class:

```
global class CustomIterable implements Iterator<SObject>{ 

List<SObject> sobjs {get; set;} 
Integer i {get; set;} 
public CustomIterable(){ 
   sobjs = new List<SObject>();

   List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, Name, OFAC_Last_Check_Date__c,OFAC_Passed__c FROM Account]; 
   for( Account acc : accs ) {
       sobjs.add(acc);
   }

   List<Contact> cons = [SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, OFAC_Last_Check_Date__c,OFAC_Passed__c FROM Contact]; 
   for( Contact con : cons ) {
       sobjs.add(con);
   }
   i = 0; 
}   
global boolean hasNext(){ 
   if(i >= sobjs.size()) 
       return false; 
   else 
       return true; 
}    
global SObject next(){ 
   if(i == 8){ i++; return null;} 
   i=i+1; 
   return sobjs[i-1]; 
} 
}
```

This is how I call the above code:

```
global Iterable<SObject> start(Database.batchableContext info){ 
    //Iterable<SObject> myIter = (Iterable<SObject>)new CustomIterable();
    return new CustomIterable(); 
}
```

I followed [this example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_iterable.htm) from the documentation.  I am trying use two objects in the batch job, hence the custom iterable.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't have anything to add to Adrian's response.... but I am a busybody and will comment anyway. Why did you choose to implement a custom iterator instead of including the contacts as a subquery within the initial account query? 

Pure curiosity, I admit.

Comment: The client is using a customized NPSP and is treating contacts and accounts as two separate, independent objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Custom Iterators](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_iterable.htm), you are mixing up `Iterable` and `Iterator` (crazy, I know). You need to return an `Iterable` where you are using an `Iterator` (you only implement the latter). Fortunately, you can just implement both.

```
class CustomIteratable implements Iterable<SObject>, Iterator<SObject>
{
    public Iterator<SObject> iterator() { return this; }
    public Boolean hasNext() { /*implementation*/ }
    public SObject next() { /*implementation*/ }
}
```